# How to sync controllers when usb doesn't work?

Tags: technical-issues, ps4

Ok so where do I start, years ago (about 2 or 3) I just bought the PS4, after a couple of months the USB ports (Both) stopped working where I plug my controller in. And then my controller desycned randomly so I am stuck, I can't plug my controller in to sync it, nor control the actual PS4. What do I do?

And can I use a converter in another non controller port, to turn it into a controller port. And sync it from that port. 
So for example can I buy a HDMI converter to plug my controller in and control the PS4 using this?

Is there any more solutions?

Comment: are you sure you are using original usb cable that comes with PS4? Have you tried USB port on the back of PS4 ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you can try, but eventually you'll have to probably take the console in for repair since it seems the USB Interface IC is probably toast. Repairing it on your own is possible but it's hard work and you can damage the circuit (more about this later).

First thing I would try is get a different USB cable and try all ports again. It's quite possible the cable failed but that's very unlikely.

You can use a battery pack or micro USB charger (most cellphones have one of those) to charge the controller but since you said your controller desynced, that won't help you much.

Next, you can buy or borrow a second controller and use it to sync the other one.

Lastly, if different cables fail and the second controller isn't working via USB, you need to face the fact that the USB Interface IC failed.

Here's a video on how to repair it:

**I absolutely don't recommend trying this** unless you have previous experience.

*You cannot use an HDMI to USB adapter to control the PS4.*